# totally different dom structure based on different value in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have a complex menu like this

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <p>Lorem ipsum....</p>
        <h3>hello</h3>
    <li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

how can apply ng-repeat to this list? Something like

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in menu" ... [if item.title=="home"]>
        <p>Lorem ipsum....</p>
        <h3>hello</h3>
    </li>
    <li [elese for all other titles]>
        <a href="#">item.val</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `ng-if` directive. See DOC [HERE](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in menu">           
     <div ng-if="item.title=='home'">
       <p>Lorem ipsum....</p>
        <h3>hello</h3>
     </div>
    </li>
    <li ng-if="item.title!='home'">
        <a href="#">item.val</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

*FYI:*

`ngIf` is a version of `ngSwitch` based on single condition

<kbd>**[Demo that demonstrates ng-switch, ng-if](http://codepen.io/xmlilley/full/GtsEb)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

[ng-switch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch) is your friend here.

I would create a directive for each DOM structure, and use `ng-switch` to call the relevant one. Something along the lines of:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in menu" ng-switch on="item.title">
      <div homeDirective ng-switch-when="home">Settings Div</div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this;

```
   <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in menu" ng-switch on="item.title">
          <p ng-switch-when="home">
            <p>Lorem ipsum....</p>
            <h3>hello</h3>
          </p>
        </li>
        <li ng-switch-default>
            <a href="#">{{item.val}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```